# C Program cannot run

Tags: c

The program i am trying to run in C shows a lot of problems and I can't do much about it.
I use the GCC compiler btw.

i used mostly long doubles for precision but i found a post here that says it will mess with the scanf function down the line so i just left it here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.141592654

long double cosl(long double x);
double sin(double x);

long double
func(long double n)
{
    long double fx;
    long double incos = ((n * PI) / 2);

    long double dnmt1 = ((n * n) * (n - 1));
    long double nmrt1 = (cos(incos));

    long double nmrt2 = (long double) (sin((n * PI) / 2));

    long double dmnt2 = (exp((1 / 2 - n)) * (n - 2));

    if (n > 1) {
        fx = nmrt1 / dnmt1;
        printf("%ld", fx);
        return fx;
    }
    else {
        fx = nmrt2 / dmnt2;
        printf("%ld", fx);
        return fx;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    long double x;

    printf("Dwse enan arithmo: ");
    scanf("%ld", &x);
    long double func(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The program takes the number but has no output even with the printf or the return in func()
I honestly am left without any other options.

[image related to the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OCrq.jpg)

Comment: Don't' post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text.  You output is text. You can copy/paste text from your console.

Comment: 1. `%ld` is not for `long double`. 2. `long double func(x);` doesn't do anything, it just declares (again) the `func` function , you probably wanted `long double some_value = func(x);`. BTW are you sure you need `long double`? On your platform `long double` is most likely the same as `double`. BTW: what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should make sure you use a proper indentation style where you immediately can see the structure of your code. As is it looks as if most of your code was on file scope, which it isn't.

Comment: This is not how you call functions in C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

1. In `main`, you have a prototype and *not* a call/invocation of `func`
2. `long double` needs `%Lf`
3. You're not using `M_PI`
4. You're duplicating prototypes that are already in `math.h`

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// NOTE/BUG: math.h has a full definition of pi
#if 0
#define PI 3.141592654
#else
#define PI M_PI
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: math.h already has prototypes for these functions
#if 0
long double cosl(long double x);
double sin(double x);
#endif

long double
func(long double n)
{
    long double fx;
    long double incos = ((n * PI) / 2);

    long double dnmt1 = ((n * n) * (n - 1));
    long double nmrt1 = (cos(incos));

    long double nmrt2 = (long double) (sin((n * PI) / 2));

    long double dmnt2 = (exp((1 / 2 - n)) * (n - 2));

    if (n > 1) {
        fx = nmrt1 / dnmt1;
#if 0
        printf("%ld", fx);
#else
        printf("%Lf\n", fx);
#endif
        return fx;
    }
    else {
        fx = nmrt2 / dmnt2;
#if 0
        printf("%ld", fx);
#else
        printf("%Lf\n", fx);
#endif
        return fx;
    }
}

int
main(void)
{

    long double x;

    printf("Dwse enan arithmo: ");
// NOTE/BUG: incorrect format specifier for a double
#if 0
    scanf("%ld", &x);
#else
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this is a forward _declaration_ and _not_ an invocation
#if 0
    long double func(x);
#else
    func(x);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`